# What is right time of reciting Ayat al-Kursi after Salah?

Tags: salat

Abu Umamah (radi Allah-u-anhu) narrated that the Messenger of Allah (sal Allahu alaihi wa sallam) said, "Whoever recites Ayat ul-Kursi immediately after each prescribed Prayer, there will be nothing standing between him and his entering Paradise except death." [Nasai, Ibn Hibban, Darimi]
I want to ask that we should read ayat al-Kursi at the end of fardh of salah or at the end of complete salah ?

Answer (score 1):

The Hadith you said, says this:

> Rasool Allah peace be upon him said, “Whoever recites Aayatul Kursi after every Fard (Fard Salat). Only death is keeping him/her from entering Jannah. (As soon as he/she dies, will enter Jannah)
>   (Nisa’i, Ibne Habban, Ibnelsani A’n Abi Amatah Albahili Radiallah Anhu)

For more info, go to this [website](http://turntoislam.com/community/threads/the-great-virtues-and-benefits-of-ayat-al-kursi.47830/)

So it will be best if you say it after the fard of salah.